# How to cancel Alamofire.upload

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am uploading images on server via `Alamofire.upload` as multipart data. Unlike `Alamofire.request` it's not returning `Request` object, which I usually use to cancel requests.

But it's very reasonable to be able to cancel such a consuming requests like uploading. What are the options for this in Alamofire?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using the [**Uploading MultiPartFormData**](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipartformdata) example from the Alamofire README:

```
Alamofire.upload(
    .POST,
    "https://httpbin.org/post",
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
    },
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .Success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .Failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

Here, `upload.responseJSON` returns a `Request`, which should allow you to assign it to something for cancellation later. For example:

```
let request = upload.responseJSON {  ...

...

request.cancel()
```

Comment: How to add parameters into the upload(Swift 3)?

Comment: My app always crash on the request.cancel(), how you did it success?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't, according to the Alamofire source code the `upload` function returns an `Request` type in all of its overloads **except** in these that support **MultipartFormData** see the following code:

```
// MARK: MultipartFormData

/**
Creates an upload request using the shared manager instance for the specified method and URL string.

- parameter method:                  The HTTP method.
- parameter URLString:               The URL string.
- parameter headers: The HTTP headers. `nil` by default.
- parameter multipartFormData:       The closure used to append body parts to the `MultipartFormData`.
- parameter encodingMemoryThreshold: The encoding memory threshold in bytes. `MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold` 
                                by default.
- parameter encodingCompletion:      The closure called when the `MultipartFormData` encoding is complete.
*/
public func upload(
  method: Method,
  URLString: URLStringConvertible,
  headers: [String: String]? = nil,
  multipartFormData: MultipartFormData -> Void,
  encodingMemoryThreshold: UInt64 = Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
  encodingCompletion: (Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult -> Void)?)
{
   return Manager.sharedInstance.upload(
      method,
      URLString,
      headers: headers,
      multipartFormData: multipartFormData,
      encodingMemoryThreshold: encodingMemoryThreshold,
      encodingCompletion: encodingCompletion
   )
}

/**
Creates an upload request using the shared manager instance for the specified method and URL string.

- parameter URLRequest:              The URL request.
- parameter multipartFormData:       The closure used to append body parts to the `MultipartFormData`.
- parameter encodingMemoryThreshold: The encoding memory threshold in bytes. `MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold`
                                by default.
- parameter encodingCompletion:      The closure called when the `MultipartFormData` encoding is complete.
*/
public func upload(
  URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible,
  multipartFormData: MultipartFormData -> Void,
  encodingMemoryThreshold: UInt64 =    Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
  encodingCompletion: (Manager.MultipartFormDataEncodingResult -> Void)?)
{
   return Manager.sharedInstance.upload(
      URLRequest,
      multipartFormData: multipartFormData,
      encodingMemoryThreshold: encodingMemoryThreshold,
      encodingCompletion: encodingCompletion
   )
}
```

It's recommended when you are writing client-side code, use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

So if you want to just upload an image to the server you can use the another `upload` function overloads that returns an `Request` object and you can cancel it like in this ways proposed in the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) documentation:

```
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Default", withExtension: "png")
ler request =Alamofire.upload(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", file: fileURL)
// request.cancel()
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Here have 2 problems: 1. the upload always hang up on 2.03M, then the request to be timeout; 2. cannot get the server response data;

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to prepare a closure, and transfer a request out of "encodingCompletion"

```
class NetworkManager {
    private var closure: ((Request)->())?

    func startUpload() {
        Alamofire.upload(
            .POST,
            "https://httpbin.org/post",
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: unicornImageURL, name: "unicorn")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: rainbowImageURL, name: "rainbow")
            },
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                    self.closure?(upload)

                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                        uploadRequest = nil
                    }
                case .Failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I created "sessionManager" instance in my API class and assigned Alamofire's session manager with configuration to it.

```
    var sessionManager: SessionManager!

    // Setup request manager
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(15.0)
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(15.0)
    sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)


    sessionManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        // AppendMultipart parts
        multipartFormData.append(metadataBodyPart, withName: PartName.Metadata, mimeType: MimeType.MultiPart)
        multipartFormData.append(imageDataBodyPart, withName: PartName.Photo, mimeType: MimeType.ImageJPG)

    } // ... rest of the code
```

Then I could create a method to cancel any current request type. Note that here "(_, uploadTasks, _)" you can also have "dataTasks" & "downloadTasks" which you can also cancel if you want "(dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks)"

```
func cancelUploadRequest() {
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (_, uploadTasks, _) in
        uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
    }
}
```

You can also have smth like this:

```
func cancel(request: CancelRequestType) {
    sessionManager.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) in
        switch request {
            case .DataTask:
                dataTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                print("- - - Data task was canceled!")
            case .UploadTask:
                uploadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                print("- - - Upload task was canceled!")
            case .DownloadTask:
                downloadTasks.forEach { $0.cancel() }
                print("- - - Download task was canceled!")
            case .ZeroTask:
                print("- - - Zero tasks was found!")
        }
    }
}
```

Where "CancelRequestType" is enum. So you can call the method like `API.cancel(request: .UploadTask)`

```
enum CancelRequestType: String {
    case DownloadTask = "DownloadTask"
    case DataTask = "DataTask"
    case UploadTask = "UploadTask"
    case ZeroTask = "Zero"
}
```